# passing boost bind handlers as arguments to asio bind handlers

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, bind

Are nested boost::bind permissible, and if so what am I doing wrong? I can nest lambda in bind successfully, but not bind in bind.

## First example

### The simple case

I can manage the standard use boost::bind to pass a complex completion handler invocation where a simple one taking only error code is needed:

```
socket->receive(buffer, boost::bind(...));
```

### Nested case

but if I want to encapsulate a combination of boost asio operations (e.g. multi-stage async_connect and async_ssl_handshake).

My outer operation will be something like:

```
connect_and_ssl(socket, boost::bind(...));
```

and my first stage definition will pass the outer handler on to the second completion in another bind, so that the outer handler can be invoked at the end:

```
template<typename Socket, typename Handler>
void connect_and_ssl(Socket socket, Handler handler)
{
  socket.async_connect(endpoint, 
         boost::bind(&w::handle_connect, this, socket, handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
};

template<typename Socket, typename Handler>
void handle_connect(Socket socket, Handler handler, const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
  socket->async_handshake(handler);
}
```

however *handler* which is a *boost::bind* really does not like being part of another boost bind. I get a whole screen full of errors, about not being able to determine the type, and others.

### Lambdas work

But I find that I can easily use lambdas instead:

```
template<typename Socket, typename Handler>
void connect_and_ssl(Socket socket, Handler handler)
{
  socket.async_connect(endpoint, 
         [=](const boost::system::error_code& ec) { handle_connect(socket, handler, ec); } );
};
```

why? Lambdas are so much easier to write, and understand, but do they make possible something that was impossible with nested binds, or was I just expressing the binds wrongly?

## Second example

### Simple case

although this will compile:

```
m_ssl_socket->async_read_some(buffer, m_strand->wrap(handler));
```

### Nested case

when converting to be also invoked from a strand:

```
m_strand->post(boost::bind(&boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&>::async_read_some, m_ssl_socket, buffer, m_strand->wap(handler)));
```

it will no longer compile - no doubt due to the strand->wrap being inside a boost::bind

### Lambda

However the lamda version compiles and runs fine:

```
m_strand->post([=](){m_ssl_socket->async_read_some(buffer, m_strand->wrap(handler)); } );
```

---

I can't work it out, but I'm very glad for lamdas.

Answer (score 1):

Nested `bind` requires `protect`.

Boost Bind has it.

In C++11 you have to define one yourself (e.g. using `reference_wrapper`).

Comment: Coming up with a sample after reading your question more closely

Comment: Didn't succeed for now. I'm going to give up becuase I might just be tired. Revisiting later

Comment: Thanks for your kind efforts.

The protect clue is useful, I note: **The header boost/bind/protect.hpp contains an implementation of protect. To protect a bind function object from evaluation, use protect(bind(f, ...))** from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html